# binary structures in node.js

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

I am writing a server, and through TCP I receive buffers. This buffers are a structure,

So I C, usually it is done like:

```
typedef struct _ref_{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t *y;
    uint8_t z[16];
}REF;
```

Unrelated to code above, my buffer could look like:

```
01 00 00 00 0A
```

Could be defined as: (little endian)

```
UINT16 UINT16 UINT8
```

So that would be

```
1, 0, 10
```

I would want to convert this into a json object like

```
UINT16 is X, UINT16 is Y, UINT8 is Z
```

Then result would be

```
x: 1, y: 0, z: 10
```

But how could it be done in node.js (not browser related)

---

I saw [restructjs](https://github.com/rfw/restruct.js) but it doesn't support strings that are null terminated, the strings are length specific.

I also saw [struct-fu](https://github.com/natevw/struct-fu) which is a bit more recent but still problems with null terminated strings.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution, that supports signed/unsigned short/long integer/float numbers and null-terminated strings in different encodings or just simple one that supports singed with specific number of bytes and ASCII strings?

Comment: Simple one that supports unsigned with specific number of bytes, in little endian order, that can also do ASCII strings, that are null terminated or not.

Comment: What do you mean by not-null terminated strings? How to detect end of string then?

Comment: Yes, both of them can parse strings if the string is given a specific length. Like a buffer contains 2 string, delimited by a null. they could be of any length. but they are always `to, and from`. so `to: 'thistle first string', from: 'this the 2nd string'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for suitable libraries I have decided to write my own that supports null-terminated strings.

It is called `c-struct` and you can find it [here](https://github.com/majimboo/c-struct).

Instal:

```
npm install c-struct --save
```

Syntax:

```
var playerSchema = new _.Schema({
  id: _.type.uint16,
  name: _.type.string(16),
  hp: _.type.uint24,
  exp: _.type.uint32,
  status: _.type.uint8,
  motd: _.type.string(), // null-terminated if no length
  motw: _.type.string(), // cstring if no length
  skills: [{
    id: _.type.uint8,
    name: _.type.string(32),
    secret: _.type.uint40
  }],
  position: {
    x: _.type.uint16,
    y: _.type.uint16
  },
  hash: _.type.uint48
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var buffer = your_input_data;

var result = {
  x: buffer.readUInt16LE(0),
  y: buffer.readUInt16LE(2),
  z: buffer.readUInt8(4)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: nope, not with the built-in buffer. I'm looking for something more like the python struct but the result is an object.